# Adding a video to Simulation Environment

Tags: nao-robot, webots, arena-simulation

I am using Webots to simulate an orchestra environment. I am trying an NAO robot to react to a video and audio,  I am unable to include the video source in the environment.
[Sample Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bPwA4gVobJ0&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=BochenLi)
Which simulator should I use or how will I create an environment to test a robot with my algorithm?

Comment: provide your code, provide what u have tried etc....

Answer (score 0):

I do not expect Webots to support embedding video in the simulated world.
Webots also already takes over the virtual NAO's video input, so you might be unable to inject your own video instead.

But if you worked with the virtual NAO created by Choregraphe (instead of Webots), you can use [`ALVideoDevice.putImage`](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/vision/alvideodevice-api.html#ALVideoDeviceProxy::putImage__iCR.iCR.iCR.AL::ALValueCR). See [ALVideoDevice documentation](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/vision/alvideodevice.html?highlight=video%20simulation#managing-simulation).